# Bias in the normalisation of gene expression due to low counts

Tags: distributions, normalization, bioinformatics

I hope it is okay to ask a question because I am one of the silent user or this forum. My background is in biology and I am not so confident in my skills in stats

The goal of the analysis is to identify genome sites (locus) that display the highest gene expression. I can not go into details of the experimental setup but we are able to know the value of a gene expression and its initial copy number.

In order to rank the genome loci with the highest expression potential, we normalise the value of gene expression we measured to the initial copy number for each locus.

|  | expression | copy number | normalised expression | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| locus1 | 10,0 | 6 | 1,7 | 3 |
| locus2 | 12,0 | 2 | 6,0 | 1 |
| locus3 | 6,0 | 2 | 3,0 | 2 |
| locus4 | 3,0 | 0,5 | 6,0 | 1 |

The loci are then rank based on the highest normalised expression.

The issue we are facing is that there seems to be an overrepresentation of the loci with very low copy numbers. If we take the top 25, 23 of them show a very small copy number value. Much lower than the mean and median of the copy number value.

It’s not very surprising since sometime the copy number is very low and we end up dividing relatively low expression value by very small copy number, this inflates the normalised expression value and make it pop at the top of the rank.

So far the solution, we have found to limit this issue is to set a hard cut-off on the copy number. So in our pilot experiment we set a minimum copy number of 4. All loci that had a smaller copy number than 4 were excluded.

This is only based on trial and errors and seems to be giving us the best results for this experiment. So probably not working in other experiments where the distribution of the value of copy number would be different.

So my question is how do you handle situations where your metric can be affected by the denominator?

Our experimental setup allows to have 3 biological replicates for the expressions, each of the value of expression can be linked to its initial value of copy number. We also noticed that the variation is stronger for lower copy number of a replicate than for higher copy number.

The distribution of values for the copy number and for the expression is quite large.

I hope that my phrasing is not too confusing.

Comment: Is the "initial copy number of each locus" the _genomic_ copy number of the locus or the number of copies of transcripts from the locus? That makes a big difference here.

Comment: the initial copy number refers to the genomic copy number of the locus. An other way of saying it, is that I have multiple copy of the same genes transfected and it differs per gene.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to normalize this way to assess a gene's "expression potential." You then implicitly assume that, other things being equal, there will be gene expression directly proportional to the number of copies of the transfected gene. That seems unlikely biologically, as there are likely to be cellular regulatory mechanisms that tamp down expression from highly over-transfected genes. Such regulatory mechanisms probably underlie what you report, with genes at low transfected copy numbers typically showing the highest expression *per transfected copy*.

You need to have some way to account and correct for such non-proportionality between expression and transfected copies. I'd suggest plotting (maybe on a log scale) the expression against the transfected copy number for all genes that you are evaluating, and looking for genes that have higher expression than others *at comparable transfected copy numbers*. Experiments that directly manipulate the number of transfected copies would also help.

Comment: Thank for your insights! So you are suggesting that in order to take into account those regulatory mechanisms we could test different quantities of transfected plasmid and measure the gene expression?

Comment: @black_cleaver yes. That would help tease apart the effects of copy-number _per se_ from any gene-specific "expression potential."